# unknown ping error in Unity when calling a punRpc

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer

we have this error which comes up exactly every 5 seconds and I couldn't find anywhere infos about it or how to fix it.
[screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQQ2S.png)

```
RPC method 'RPC_ReceivePing' found on object with PhotonView 1001 but has wrong parameters. Implement as 'RPC_ReceivePing(Int32)'. PhotonMessageInfo is optional as final parameter.Return type must be void or IEnumerator (if you enable RunRpcCoroutines).
UnityEngine.Debug:LogErrorFormat (UnityEngine.Object,string,object[])
Photon.Pun.PhotonNetwork:ExecuteRpc (ExitGames.Client.Photon.Hashtable,Photon.Realtime.Player) (at Assets/Plugins/PhotonUnityNetworking/Code/PhotonNetworkPart.cs:646)
Photon.Pun.PhotonNetwork:RPC (Photon.Pun.PhotonView,string,Photon.Pun.RpcTarget,Photon.Realtime.Player,bool,object[]) (at Assets/Plugins/PhotonUnityNetworking/Code/PhotonNetworkPart.cs:1266)
Photon.Pun.PhotonNetwork:RPC (Photon.Pun.PhotonView,string,Photon.Pun.RpcTarget,bool,object[]) (at Assets/Plugins/PhotonUnityNetworking/Code/PhotonNetwork.cs:2940)
Photon.Pun.PhotonView:RPC (string,Photon.Pun.RpcTarget,object[]) (at Assets/Plugins/PhotonUnityNetworking/Code/PhotonView.cs:609)
FirstGearGames.PhotonNetworking.Utilities.MasterClientMonitor:CheckSendPing () (at Assets/01_Batvision/05_Scripts/GameLogic/MasterClientMonitor.cs:299)
FirstGearGames.PhotonNetworking.Utilities.MasterClientMonitor:Update () (at Assets/01_Batvision/05_Scripts/GameLogic/MasterClientMonitor.cs:127)
```

it's telling me that some RPC parameter is wrong but I checked every single one in the project and can't seem to find what they mean.
[screenshot of all rpc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yy6Zg.png)

here's an example of one of the RPC
[example of my rpc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ej9B.png)

```
void Update()
{
   if (HasCrossedTheRing == true)
    {
        
         photonView.RPC("ConfirmRing", RpcTarget.All);
         PhotonNetwork.SendAllOutgoingCommands();
        
    }
}

[PunRPC]
public void ConfirmRing()
{
    if (HasCrossedTheRing == true)
    {
        mainRingTimerObj.StopTimer();
        NextInsectObjCin.LookAtRoots();
        rootsAdd.addColorRoot();
        HasCrossedTheRing = false;

    }
}
```

would anyone have an idea what the error means or how I can find on which RPC the problem comes from?

thanks for your time,

HD

I tried deleting all unused RPC in the project and check that it wasn't a spelling error and the so called bool "RunRpcCoroutines" is already set to false

the MasterClientMonitor.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Photon.Pun;
using Photon.Realtime;
using System.Linq;

namespace FirstGearGames.PhotonNetworking.Utilities
{

    public class MasterClientMonitor : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
    {
        #region Types.
        /// <summary>
        /// Holds a players ping.
        /// </summary>
        private class PlayerPing
        {
            public PlayerPing(Player player, int ping)
            {
                Player = player;
                _pings.Add(ping);
            }
            /// <summary>
            /// Last time a ping was set for this player.
            /// </summary>
            public float LastUpdatedTime { get; private set; } = -1f;
            /// <summary>
            /// Player this instance is for.
            /// </summary>
            public readonly Player Player;
            /// <summary>
            /// Pings for this player.
            /// </summary>
            private List<int> _pings = new List<int>();
            /// <summary>
            /// Maximum number of ping history to allow.
            /// </summary>
            private const int MAXIMUM_RECORDED_PINGS = 6;

            /// <summary>
            /// Returns the average ping for this player. Returns -1f if recorded ping quantity is not at maximum recorded pings.
            /// </summary>
            /// <returns></returns>
            public int ReturnAveragePing()
            {
                //Not enough pings to consider an average yet.
                if (_pings.Count < MAXIMUM_RECORDED_PINGS)
                {
                    return -1;
                }
                //Has enough pings to return average.
                else
                {
                    int sum = _pings.Sum();
                    return Mathf.CeilToInt(sum / _pings.Count);
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Adds a ping for this player. Replaces oldest ping if at maximum recorded pings.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="value"></param>
            public void AddPing(int value)
            {
                //If at max pings remove the first entry.
                if (_pings.Count >= MAXIMUM_RECORDED_PINGS)
                    _pings.RemoveAt(0);

                _pings.Add(value);
                LastUpdatedTime = Time.unscaledTime;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Private.
        /// <summary>
        /// List of player pings.
        /// </summary>
        private List<PlayerPing> _playerPings = new List<PlayerPing>();
        /// <summary>
        /// Next time to check for a high ping on master client.
        /// </summary>
        private float _nextCheckChangeMaster = 0f;
        /// <summary>
        /// Number of times in a row the current master client has had a significantly higher ping.
        /// </summary>
        private int _consequtiveHighPingCount = 0;
        /// <summary>
        /// True if received a master client change request. This is only set on master client.
        /// </summary>
        private bool _pendingMasterChange = false;
        /// <summary>
        /// Time a takeover request was sent. -1f if no takeover request is active.
        /// </summary>
        private float _takeoverRequestTime = -1f;
        /// <summary>
        /// Next time to send ping for this client.
        /// </summary>
        private float _nextSendPingTime = 0f;
        #endregion

        #region Const.
        /// <summary>
        /// How many times in a row the current masters ping must be significantly higher than others to forfeit master client.
        /// </summary>
        private const int HIGH_PING_TURNOVER_REQUIREMENT = 3;
        /// <summary>
        /// Mimimum current master client pings must be higher than lowest pinging player to be considered significantly higher.
        /// </summary>
        private const int MINIMUM_PING_DIFFERENCE = 50;
        /// <summary>
        /// How often to check for lowest pings. Masterclient must have a high ping after HIGH_PING_TURNOVER_REQUIREMENT times.
        /// </summary>
        private const float PING_CHECK_INTERVAL = 5f;
        /// <summary>
        /// Time master client has to grant a takeover request before it's taken forcefully. It's preferred that the master grants the request to prevent multiple takeovers in a short duration, but when master client is laggy or broken this may not be possible.
        /// </summary>
        private const float TAKEOVER_REQUEST_TIMEOUT = 3f;
        /// <summary>
        /// How frequently to send this clients ping.
        /// </summary>
        private const float SEND_PING_INTERVAL = 5f;
        #endregion

        private void Update()
        {
            CheckSendPing();
            CheckChangeMaster();
            CheckTakeoverTimeout();
        }

        public override void OnPlayerLeftRoom(Player otherPlayer)
        {
            //See if player is in player pings. If so remove them.
            int index = _playerPings.FindIndex(x => x.Player == otherPlayer);
            if (index != -1)
                _playerPings.RemoveAt(index);
        }

        public override void OnMasterClientSwitched(Player newMasterClient)
        {
            base.OnMasterClientSwitched(newMasterClient);
            //Unset pending master change.
            _pendingMasterChange = false;
            //Reset takeover data.
            _takeoverRequestTime = -1f;
            _consequtiveHighPingCount = 0;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Checks if a takeover needs to be forced. Usually occurs when the master client doesn't respond in time.
        /// </summary>
        private void CheckTakeoverTimeout()
        {
            //No takeover in progress.
            if (_takeoverRequestTime == -1f)
                return;

            //Master client request timed out. Takeover forcefully.
            if ((Time.unscaledTime - _takeoverRequestTime) > TAKEOVER_REQUEST_TIMEOUT)
            {
                _takeoverRequestTime = -1f;
                SetNewMaster(PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets a new master client.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="newMaster"></param>
        private void SetNewMaster(Player newMaster, bool resetHighPingCount = true)
        {
            if (resetHighPingCount)
                _consequtiveHighPingCount = 0;
            //Set new master and use takeover.
            PhotonNetwork.SetMasterClient(newMaster);
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Checks to change master if the current master is significantly more laggy than other players.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private void CheckChangeMaster()
        {
            //Network conditions not met.
            if (!PhotonNetwork.IsConnected || !PhotonNetwork.InRoom || PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient)
                return;
            //Takeover already in progress.
            if (_takeoverRequestTime != -1f)
                return;
            //Too recent since last check.
            if (Time.time < _nextCheckChangeMaster)
                return;

            //Next time to check pings.
            _nextCheckChangeMaster = Time.time + PING_CHECK_INTERVAL;

            /* Players should already be removed when leaving the room.
             * This is just an extra precautionary. */
            RemoveNullPlayers();

            //Get list of all players.
            Player[] players = PhotonNetwork.PlayerList;
            //If only one player.
            if (players.Length <= 1)
                return;

            int lowestAverageIndex = -1;
            int lowestAveragePing = -1;
            int masterPing = -1;
            int masterIndex = -1;

            foreach (Player player in players)
            {
                int pingsIndex = _playerPings.FindIndex(x => x.Player == player);
                //Not found in players pings.
                if (pingsIndex == -1)
                    continue;

                //If player being checked is this client.
                if (player == PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer)
                {
                    //If this client hasn't sent a ping in awhile don't even try to takeover.
                    if ((Time.unscaledTime - _playerPings[pingsIndex].LastUpdatedTime) >= (SEND_PING_INTERVAL * 2))
                        return;
                }

                //Get average.
                int averagePing = _playerPings[pingsIndex].ReturnAveragePing();
                //If average isn't -1 then enough pings have been sent to calculate an average.
                if (averagePing != -1)
                {
                    /* If average ping is lowest than the current lowest or
                     * the lowest average index is -1 (which means unset) then
                     * set as new lowest average. */
                    if (averagePing < lowestAveragePing || lowestAverageIndex == -1)
                    {
                        lowestAveragePing = averagePing;
                        lowestAverageIndex = pingsIndex;
                    }
                    //If player being checked is master client.
                    if (_playerPings[pingsIndex].Player.IsMasterClient)
                    {
                        masterIndex = pingsIndex;

                        /* If master client hasn't send a ping within a reasonable time then
                         * set the master clients ping unrealistically high to force a high
                         * consequtive ping count. */
                        if ((Time.unscaledTime - _playerPings[masterIndex].LastUpdatedTime) >= (SEND_PING_INTERVAL * 2))
                            masterPing = 999999999;
                        //Otherwise set to average ping.
                        else
                            masterPing = averagePing;
                    }
                }
            }

            //If the lowest ping index couldn't be found.
            if (lowestAverageIndex == -1)
                return;
            //Master index couldn't be found.
            if (masterIndex == -1)
                return;
            /* If the lowest ping index isn't this client then
             * don't proceed further, let the lowest pinging player
             * try the take over when the time comes. */
            if (_playerPings[lowestAverageIndex].Player != PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer)
                return;

            /* If here this client is the lowest pinging player. */

            float masterPingDifference = (masterPing - lowestAveragePing);
            //If master ping is difference is high enough to change master client.
            if (masterPingDifference > MINIMUM_PING_DIFFERENCE)
                _consequtiveHighPingCount++;
            //master ping not too much higher.
            else
                _consequtiveHighPingCount = 0;

            //If high ping 3 times in a row then request setting a new master.
            if (_consequtiveHighPingCount >= 3)
            {
                _takeoverRequestTime = Time.unscaledTime;
                base.photonView.RPC("RPC_RequestMasterClient", RpcTarget.MasterClient, _playerPings[lowestAverageIndex].Player);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sends ping to all players including self.
        /// </summary>
        private void CheckSendPing()
        {
            if (Time.unscaledTime < _nextSendPingTime)
                return;

            _nextSendPingTime = Time.unscaledTime + SEND_PING_INTERVAL;

            base.photonView.RPC("RPC_ReceivePing", RpcTarget.All, PhotonNetwork.GetPing());
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Receives a ping for the specified player.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="player"></param>
        /// <param name="ping"></param>
        [PunRPC]
        private void RPC_ReceivePing(Player player, int ping)
        {
            int index = _playerPings.FindIndex(x => x.Player == player);
            if (index == -1)
                _playerPings.Add(new PlayerPing(player, ping));
            else
                _playerPings[index].AddPing(ping);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Removes null players from player pings list.
        /// </summary>
        private void RemoveNullPlayers()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _playerPings.Count; i++)
            {
                //If null player remove from list and decrease i.
                if (_playerPings[i].Player == null)
                {
                    _playerPings.RemoveAt(i);
                    i--;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Request releasing the master client to the requestor.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="requestor">Player requesting the change.</param>
        /// Master client required.
        [PunRPC]
        private void RPC_RequestMasterClient(Player requestor)
        {
            //A change is already pending.
            if (_pendingMasterChange)
                return;
            //If not master.
            if (!PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient)
                return;

            _pendingMasterChange = true;
            //RPC to allow change.
            base.photonView.RPC("RPC_MasterClientGranted", requestor);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Received on a player which may takeover as master client.
        /// </summary>
        [PunRPC]
        private void RPC_MasterClientGranted()
        {
            //Set new master as self.
            SetNewMaster(PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Called when the game gains or loses focus.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="pause"></param>
        private void OnApplicationPause(bool pause)
        {
            if (pause)
                LocallyHandOffMasterClient();
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Called when the game gains or loses focus.
        /// </summary>
        private void OnApplicationFocus(bool focus)
        {
            if (!focus)
                LocallyHandOffMasterClient();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Hands off master client to the lowest pinging player at this time.
        /// </summary>
        private void LocallyHandOffMasterClient()
        {
            //Conditions where this does not apply.
            if (!PhotonNetwork.IsConnected || !PhotonNetwork.InRoom || !PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient)
                return;
            //Only player.
            if (PhotonNetwork.PlayerList.Length <= 1)
                return;

            //Other index which isn't this client.
            int otherIndex = -1;

            int lowestIndex = -1;
            int lowestPing = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < _playerPings.Count; i++)
            {
                //Skip self.
                if (_playerPings[i].Player == PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer)
                    continue;

                otherIndex = i;

                int average = _playerPings[i].ReturnAveragePing();
                //If new lowest or lowest isnt yet set.
                if (average < lowestPing || lowestIndex == -1)
                {
                    lowestIndex = i;
                    lowestPing = average;
                }
            }

            //If the lowest ping was found.
            if (lowestIndex != -1)
            {
                SetNewMaster(_playerPings[lowestIndex].Player);
            }
            //Lowest ping not found. Maybe not enough data is collected.
            else
            {
                /* Can only proceed if an index of another player was found.
                 * If so send to the last player checked which wasnt self. */
                if (otherIndex != -1)
                    SetNewMaster(_playerPings[otherIndex].Player);
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Hi user20823178, please post your error in formatted code as opposed to an image, so that others are better able to help! Thanks :)

Comment: Hi Juris, how do I do it to show an error from the console? thanks a lot, HD

Comment: You could replace the link to the error image with a copy of the console output by using a [formatted code segment](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: could you also show the code at `Assets/01_Batvision/05_Scripts/GameLogic/MasterClientMonitor.cs:299`? it seems from the stacktrace the problem comes from there.

Comment: @pixlhero thankl a lot for your time. I added it but it's a default script from photon that we didnt touch